# Handling multiple forms on a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a page that is mostly informational data (not an input form, overall). And it has a title that can be edited.

Clicking the Edit Title button pops up a modal window where the user can edit the title and hit submit.

Because this form is a very small part of the page, and because I may need other small forms on the same page, I just created a small handler in the controller to handle this one submit.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PageTitle(string title)
{
    // ... Save new title to the database ...

    // I have no PageTitle page, so just redirect back to the source page
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

This works okay, but I don't like the extra redirect here. A redirect back to the client causes another round trip back to the server.

Is there a more efficient way to handle small forms on a page, where you don't want to resubmit every input element on the page each time?

Comment: How are you submitting the form ? Normal form post or ajax ? If ajax, there will not be a redirect

Comment: @Shyju: Just a normal post with a submit button. I know I can use AJAX, but the extra work of updating the parts of the page that changed isn't justified here.

Comment: As long as they're not nested, you can have as many forms on a page as you want. Submitting one form won't submit the other forms' values, so is the primary concern that you have to reload everything on the redirect?

Comment: @TiesonT.: No, I'm okay with reloading the entire page. The primary concern is the additional redirect with another round trip back to the server.

Comment: Post-redirect-get is a standard pattern. The only other option is the aforementioned AJAX. Have you looked into the AjaxHelper class? If configured properly, it handles most of the page updating.

Comment: Are you saying that after a user clicks the submit button the page loads twice?

Comment: @BillRuhl: No, why would it? Instead, it sends a redirect back to the browser and the browser requests the new page.

Comment: Can you add an example of how you have your views constructed? Assuming it's okay to return JSON from your action, you don't really need to refresh the page, if I'm understanding your use-case correctly, and it doesn't take much to do a partial-page refresh.

Comment: @TiesonT.: Yes, AJAX is a viable way to make this very efficient. But there is a bit of effort that just isn't warranted. I can stick with the redirect and no one will ever complain. The redirect just felt inefficient to me and I wanted a discussion to explore the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TiesonT. points out, post/redirect/get is a standard pattern. No, it doesn't seem like the most efficient. But without doing AJAX or something a little more elaborate, there is really no way to postback to a specialized handler and then refresh the page without a redirect.

Was hoping I overlooked something simple but it looks like I did not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a convenient way how to avoid the redirection after a post request (without using Ajax).

You can of course return any View:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessForm1(FormOneData data)
{
    // process form
    return View("Index");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessForm2(FormTwoData data)
{
    // process form
    return View("Index");
}
```

So the user will get the same page but the problem with this solution is that the url will be different.

You can have one function for GET request, another for POST requests, both with the same URL. But than you would have to figure out how one action method would handle more forms - doable but terrible for maintenance.

And this can get even more complicated if those forms can appear on more than one page.

But actually, it solves one thing. With the redirection you avoid the re-POST dialog that user gets if they press F5 (and sometimes submit the form again by mistake).

Comment: Not only would the user get a strange URL, but you'd have to duplicate any logic in the controller method.

Comment: Not necessarily an issue. Most of my controller methods have just one line. But the bottom line is that it can cause a lot of troubles trying to limit the redirection and it's not worth it :)

Answer (score 0):

What about sending form data via Ajax as shown below?

```
@model Models.YourModel

$('form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
 
    //Send the values of all form controls within the <form> tags including the token
    var formdata = $('#frmRegister').serialize();
 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("ProcessForm", "Controller")',
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: formdata,
            
        error: function (response) {
            $("#error_message").html(data);
        },
 
        success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

You can also use [Partial Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial) in order to use multiple forms or fragment on the same View.